# wp-admin and wp-login.php not Accessible after Cloudflare

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess, cloudflare

I have the following `.htaccess` rule to limit access to `wp-admin` and `wp-login.php` locally via SSH dynamic forwarding:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

However, after installing Cloudflare I cannot access `/wp-admin` and `wp-login.php` anymore. Previously, I have the following lines in my `access.log`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2019:06:30:12 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200
```

But now the IP was changed to cloudflare's:

```
162.158.166.167 - - [20/Jun/2019:09:42:51 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 403
```

How can I solve this problem? Do I need to include all of cloudflare's IP to my `.htaccess` rule? If I do that, will I expose my `wp-admin` and `wp-login.php` to other cloudflare users too?

EDIT: Solved it using [mod_cloudflare](https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare).

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Cloudflare features on admin pages for content management systems like WordPress

To avoid getting a site offline error message when updating the admin section of your content management system, we recommend setting a Page Rule to exclude the admin section of your CMS from Cloudflare.

Please do the following on the Page Rule interface (we'll use WordPress admin section as an example):

1. Go to the Cloudflare Page Rule app.
2. Input the URL for the admin section, which is in this format: example.com/wp-admin/
3. Place a * before and after the URL, so it reads as *example.com/wp-admin/*.
4. For "Cache Level", choose "Bypass"
5. For Performance, choose "Disable Performance"
6. For security, choose "Disable Security"
7. Save the rule

for more details please have a look
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169526-Disabling-Cloudflare-features-on-admin-pages-for-content-management-systems-like-WordPress